# Cannnot pass a value into a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I wanted to pass the value, it didn't worked.
This is my code,

```
function showimage(b)
{
    //if alert was here, it would show the value of b
    $("#lightboxholder").show("fast","",function (b)
    {
        alert(b);//but now when the alert is here, it is not showing the value of b
    });
}
```

am I missing something guys? thanks in advance!

Comment: you dont need to pass b in lightbox handler just directly use it in alert is that fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vntjv/)**

```
function showimage(b)
{
    //if alert was here, it would show the value of b
    $("#lightboxholder").show("fast", function ()
    {
        alert(b);//but now when the alert is here, it is not showing the value of b
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The inner function will be called with new arguments, so `b` will be replaced with a new variable.

if you replace `function (b)` with `function ()` - then the inner `b` should be the one given to the outer function.

Comment: `function showimage(b)
{
 
 $("#lightboxholder").show("fast","",function ()
 {
  alert(b);
 });
}` still not working, it is not showing the value

Comment: Weird - are you sure that `b` is being initialised at the start of the function? perhaps a second alert would let you know: `function showimage(b) { alert("outer:"+b); $("#lightboxholder").show("fast","",function () { alert("inner:"+b); }); }`

Answer (score 1):

That would be because the local value of `b` in the function is overriding the value of `b` in the showImage function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start off simple and give you code that does what you want:

```
function showimage(b)
{
    //if alert was here, it would show the value of b
    $("#lightboxholder").show("fast","",function ()
    {
        alert(b); // interestingly enough, it knows what b is here
    });
}
```

From there two main questions arise: why does what you are trying not work and why does what I am doing work. Let's start with what you are doing.

You are trying to pass a parameter to the function, as if you were calling the anonymous function. However, you aren't calling the function. You are defining the function and giving the function itself as a parameter to jQuery. jQuery then calls the function you have defined at the point it wishes to. Because it would need to supply the value at that point and doesn't, you won't get the result you are looking to achieve. Hence, you can't pass arguments the way you are trying to.

Then let's move on to why my version does work. This is what is called encapsulation in javascript. Basically, if you define a function, you can use any variables that are available in the context you define the function. Javascript then automatically makes sure only the ones you are used are included in the context of the function you defined. This is completely independent of where you call the function and only relies on the place you define the function. As such, I simply "borrowing" the b value from the showImage function and using in the anonymous function.